# Nested ng-repeat with no nested divs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that looks like:

```
var obj = [ 
[{x:3,y:3},{x:6,y:1},{x:3,y:5}],
[{x:1,y:3},{x:6,y:1},{x:3,y:5}],
[{x:3,y:3},{x:6,y:1},{x:3,y:5}]
]
```

Now I'd like to bind this in angular. But on the page I just want it to look like a bunch of divs (but with no nested div structures). So:

```
<div style='position:absolute; left:3px;top:3px'></div>
<div style='position:absolute; left:6px;top:1px'></div>
<div style='position:absolute; left:3px;top:5px'></div>
<div style='position:absolute; left:1px;top:3px'></div>
... and so on
```

But when I look at angular documentation it looks like I need to do:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in obj">
   <div ng-repeat="col in row">
   </div>
</div>
```

But this would created nested divs. Is there any way to create a flat div structure like I detailed above?

NOTE: Assume the data structure is as is (I can't create a flat list of objects)
^^^^^^

Comment: Oh, you can use a directive for that, give me a minute so I can build an example.

Comment: I don't know whats up with this question, it doesn't even make sense. You're wanting ng-repeat to go into the first array of objects, but repeat itself X number of times for each of objects arrays, in just one iteration of ng-repeat. What's wrong with nesting them, and what's wrong with flattening your array?

Comment: updated my answer with an alternative using directives so you can get the desired html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: as it is, no you can´t do it without nesting your divs

To do that you must modify your array, flattening it on your controller and then bind to the flattened array.
Here is a working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/KPHurN2XBkvwMW22X3MP?p=preview

Your HTML should be like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in flattenedObj" style="left:{{item.x}} top: {{item.y}}">X: {{item.x}} | Y: {{item.y}}</div>
```

Note that you can apply this flattening on your controller, but the recommended way is to use a service for that, you are probably receiving this array from an endpoint via `$http`, so treat it as you receive it.

---

**UPDATE** after reading that the structure should not be changed.

You can do this with directives, here is a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Whf5YY8kV0zjEEM8vUAN?p=preview

```
app.directive('exampleDirective',[function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      sub: '='
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    link:function($scope, elem){
      var resultingHtml = '';

      for(var i=0; i<$scope.sub.length; i++){
        resultingHtml += '<div style="top: '+ $scope.sub[i].y +'px; left: '+ $scope.sub[i].x +'px;">X:' + $scope.sub[i].x + ' Y:' + $scope.sub[i].y + ' </div>';
      }

      elem.replaceWith(resultingHtml);
    }
  }
}]);
```

If you try to make it using a `ng-repeat` on the directive´s template, angular will try to use the upper scope because of the `replace: true`, so you must do it the hard way.

Hope that helps

Comment: I guess my only issue is if one of these values inside my array (for example an one x got changed), then behind the scenes the entire html gets replaced?

Comment: That's not going to work, as I said, the best scenario is if you can flatten the array, that way the binding will work perfectly, consider doing that only for showing purposes.

Comment: @Fedaykin I have a question, where did you learn how to use directives? They seem to be the only thing about angular.js that I don't understand. You seem to be able to work with them quite quickly based off of time difference between your answer and the question being asked. Something about directives is intimidating to me.

Comment: @J-Dizzle hi, I don´t consider my self well versed on directives yet lol. I started learning from here: https://egghead.io/ (check the older videos first) and then took some courses on http://pluralsight.com (there is a free trial). Also a lot of googling :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a flat list, flatten it in the controller before binding to scope. Flattening out a list shouldn't happen in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you've got this ng-repeat which iterates through the javscript objects in your array. Access those object properties. so check this one-line out.

```
<div ng-repeat="row in obj" style="{{ 'position:absolute; left:' +row.x + 'px;top:' + row.y +'px;'}}"></div>
```

... or

```
<div ng-repeat="row in obj" style="position:absolute; left:{{row.x}}px;top:{{row.y}}px;"></div>
```

Comment: i don't think that would work as the second level is an array itself

Comment: right, so let's throw in a ng-init and flatten that array. You're making a flat div structure why isn't the array flat?

Comment: the question was specifically to see if i can bind a double dimension array to a flat div structure. see my note in the question

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot change the shape of your data, you must assume it has certain properties, such as each inner array always contains 3 objects.

```
<div ng-repeat-start="row in obj" style='position:absolute; left:{{row[0].x}}px;top:{{row[0].y}};'></div>
<div style='position:absolute; left:{{row[1].x}}px;top:{{row[1].y}};'></div>
<div ng-repeat-end style='position:absolute; left:{{row[2].x}}px;top:{{row[2].y}};'></div>
```

Comment: if those indices can't be computed automagically then not interested so much in this.. but interesting answer